# How to save values from input file to be used later in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

The goal of this visual basic program is to store inputs from a file, then output them in a label. They should be displayed one value at a time. My idea is to store the values in a index, but it's clunky, and it does not work.

The program has a next and previous buttons that increase and decrease the value of the index in the output.

This is the code I'm using.

```
    Public Sub FileModeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FileModeButton.Click

    Dim Result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

    If Result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Return
    End If

    FileOpen(1, OpenFileDialog.FileName, OpenMode.Input)

    Index = 1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        'Need to keep more than one stored set of outputs.
        Input(1, FileOutput1)
        Input(1, FileOutput2)

        FileOut1(Index) = FileOutput1
        FileOut2(Index) = FileOutput2

        Index += 1
    Loop
    FileClose(1)

End Sub

     Private Sub ApplyButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)         Handles ApplyButton.Click
    Index = 1

    If ModeComboBox.Text = "File" Then
        FileModeGroupBox.Enabled = True
        TextboxModeGroupBox.Enabled = False
        Output1Label.Text = FileOut1(Index)
        Output2Label.Text = FileOut2(Index)
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file reading is not really optimal. Try this instead (import system.IO):

```
Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
```

Then you can just do (readText must be a global variable at this point,same goes for index):

```
Output1label.Text = readText(index)
Output2label.text = readText(index)
```

On Next and Prev buttons do:

```
index = index+1 (on prev index-1)
Output1label.Text = readText(index)
Output2label.text = readText(index)
```

Also don't forget to check readText.Length to make sure you don't go out of the array size.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 doesn't recognize "File.ReadAllLines", do you know how it should look for 2010?

Comment: Sry: System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() is the full path to the function

Comment: Do you know how I could make it so it would display "Date, Sept" as two separate outputs? IE: Line 1 = Date, Line 2 = Sept

Comment: Is each line in the file Date,Sept? If that is the case just do readText(index).Split(",".ToCharArray())(0) on the first and alter 0 to 1 on the other. This splits the read line on , : 0 means string before , and 1 means string after.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Visual studio 2010 doesn't recognize this expression either. Maybe I just have it in the wrong plcae, should it be after "Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog.FileName);" ?

Comment: It should be placed like this Output1label.Text = readText(index).Split(",".ToCharArray())(0)

Comment: Output1label.Text = readText(index).Split(","c)(0) <- this works too